# Blender plugin import python from other file fail

Tags: python

I am trying to create a plug-in.
In my `__Init__.py` I am trying to import code from another file `operator_add.py`, which is located in the same folder in the same level:

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    importlib.reload(OBJECT_add)
else:
    from operator_add import OBJECT_add
```

However this does not work, when I install the plug-in it gives me an error saying the `No module named operator_add`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Should it be `importlib.reload(operator_add)`?

Answer (score 1):

`importlib.reload` only reloads modules, not arbitrary objects.

As BatFinger also suggested, import your module (so `import operator_add`), and not just one name from it (so not `from operator_add import OBJECT_add`). You can then reload it with `importlib.reload(operator_add)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think whats going on is your system isn't picking up the location of `operators_add.py` so what I would suggest doing in the `operators_add.py` and the `__init__.py` is add this in every add-on script.

```
import os
import sys 
dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if not dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(dir)
```

This should make it work fine.

edit: Do this then use imp to reload the `operators_add.py` script

Comment: The addons path is known to blender already eg `from io_scene_3ds import import_3ds` (the import 3ds addon)  there is no need to append any paths.  IMO `if dir not in sys.path` is more readable but not that important.  Quite likely needs to be `from . import operator_add` or `from .operator_add import Blah` or `from addon_module.operator_add import Blah`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that for my scripts when I was having his issue and it never worked

Comment: Every multi-file addon shipped with blender is an example that does work. If you want to run modules from text editor absolute importing `from addon_module.submodule import Blah` would be the best bet.

Comment: I gotta try to get it down weird it doesn't work for me.... maybe I am doing something wrong but Im sure I am doing it as you have said